# Getting 401 (Unauthorized) while post data Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

My data is not posting in postman api 
it gives the error:

> dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas:1 POST http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas 401 (Unauthorized)
>   core.js:4002 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas", ok: false, …}

My app.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      loadedPosts = [];

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this.fetchPosts();
      }

      onCreatePost(postData: { id: number; content: string }) {
        // Send Http request
        this.http
          .post(
            'http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas',
            postData
          )
          .subscribe(responseData => {
            console.log(responseData);
          });
      }
```

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well!

The **401 API error** occurs when you are not authorized to access a endpoint from the requested server(Read more about status codes [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)). Probably you need to check the documentation for which type of Authorization the API is using and then pass it to headers accordingly.

In Most cases it is a Bearer token attached to a request(in headers) probably like this:

```
createUserObjectApi() {
    const body = {
      name: 'traveler',
      email: 'hl_kher@rediffmail.com',
      location: 'USA',
    };

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization' : `Bearer e33e18e7-caf3-4467-9f6d-88112f91489c`
    });

    return this.httpClient.post<any>(
      'http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/users',
      body,
      {
        headers
      }
    ).subscribe((res) => {
      return res;
    })
  }
```

There are other types of authorizations available about which you can read it [here.](https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/tip/4-API-authentication-methods-to-better-protect-data-in-transit)

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Answer (score -2):

The problem do not come from Angular.
You are getting the response with the error "Unauthorized" and the HTTP Status code "401".

You are trying to requests the URL "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas" and this website tell you that you haven't access to the resource.

Maybe you need to add some credentials like username/password, token or something else to your request.

---

More information about status codes : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes